# Operator CombineLatest - is possible determine stream of last emited item?

Tags: rx-java2

I use combineLatest for join of two streams with two types of tasks. Processing two types of tasks should be interleaved. Is possible to determine which stream emits last value of pair?
I use solution with timestamp, but it is not correct. Each subject contain default value.

```
List<Flowable<? extends Timed<? extends Task>>> sources = new ArrayList<>();

Flowable<Timed<TaskModification>> modificationSource = mTaskModificationSubject
      .onBackpressureDrop()
      .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
      .timestamp();

Flowable<Timed<TaskSynchronization>> synchronizationSource = mTaskSynchronizationSubject
      .onBackpressureDrop()
      .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
      .flatMap(TaskSynchronizationWrapper::getSources)
      .timestamp();

sources.add(0, modificationSource);
sources.add(1, synchronizationSource);

return Flowable
  .combineLatest(sources, array -> {
    Timed<TaskModification> taskModification = (Timed<TaskModification>) array[0];
    Timed<TaskSynchronization> taskSynchronization = (Timed<TaskSynchronization>) array[1];
    return (taskModification.time() > taskSynchronization.time())
      ? taskModification.value()
      : taskSynchronization.value();
  }, 1)
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
  .flatMapSingle(
    Task::getSource
  )
  .ignoreElements();
```

Comment: Makes no sense. Looks like you'd want to `merge` them instead.

Comment: I have requirement that task modification should be done almost imediatelly when is added, not after finishing all tasks of synchronizations. When I use merge, than modification can be processed after processing of all synchronization (delay is 10 seconds). CombineLatest with buffer size 1 guarantees max. 2 items (without subscribers) in internal queue (one of each task type). In resut i solve it with scan operator where I cache last processed tasks and where I select task for processing. When is used combineLatest than delay is 1 second. Merge does not emit items exactly by time of insertion.

Comment: Do you understand?

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: I need to interleave tasks from both streams (modification, synchronization, modification, synchronization...) when modification tasks exist. But when I use merge than was result: synchronization, synchronization, synchronization, synchronization, synchronization, synchronization, modification.But modification occured before emitting second synchronization task. 
What should I describe better?

Comment: Do you want to order tasks by time from two sources, like [this](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowablesorderedmerge)?

Comment: Modifications and synchronizations are serialized. Yes, can be performed N synchronization of data (periodically). Wrapper contains N tasks. But when user perform modification than should be done as soon as possible.

Comment: I solve this situation by usage of combineLatest. From pair is always processes newest item. Default values for both subjects are used.I dont know why, but merge does not work properly as I expected.

Comment: I still don't see what the pattern should look like. Maybe if you drew a marble diagram with the relevant input patterns or give an unit test that has the assertions of the outcomes, that would be great.

Comment: Each 2 minutes is generated TaskSynchronizationWrapper and contains N TaskSynchronization object. TaskSynchronization object wraps API call (download data and persist them to DB). Generated object is writed to mTaskSynchronizationSubject. But can occurs situation when is during processing of synchronization tasks emitted modification task (it can be insert, update or delete - API call and persisting to DB). Both types of tasks must be serialized and modification task should be processed as soon as possible. User of app waits for finishing of operaton.

Comment: When I use merge than user must wait for example 10 x 1 seconds (processing of 10 synchronization tasks). But when I use combineLatest than user waits only 1 x 1 seconds. When user click insert button than is insertion task emitted to mTaskModificationSubject.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the concurrency on the `merge()`?

Comment: Yes, Flowable.merge(sources, 2, 1). This solution contains problems.

Comment: I still can't fully understand what your input-output pattern is; unless you write a code that demonstrates given an input what the output should be, I can't give you any further advice.

Comment: When modification task is emitted than his processing should have priority before synchronization tasks.

Comment: Problem of merge operator is that items are not emitted in order in which were recieved. Is not preserve right order. If you want to I can show it to you.

Comment: Merge is not good solution when order of items from different stream is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When modification task is emitted than should have priority before synchronization tasks.

Without implementing a custom operator, you could introduce queues, merge the signals, then pick items from the priority queue first:

```java
Flowable<X> prioritySource = ...
Flowable<X> source = ...

Flowable<X> output = Flowable.defer(() -> {
    Queue<X> priorityQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    Queue<X> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    return Flowable.merge(
         prioritySource.map(v -> {
             priorityQueue.offer(v);
             return 1;
         }),
         source.map(v -> {
             queue.offer(v);
             return 1;
         })
    )
    .map(v -> {
        if (!priorityQueue.isEmpty()) {
            return priorityQueue.poll();
        }
        return queue.poll();
    });
});
```